# how to check already exist entry in database

Tags: yii

My default controller function

```
    public function actionAddNewCategories() {

         $model = new AddNewCategory();
         $model->category_name=strip_tags(trim($_POST['categoryname']));
         $model->category_description=strip_tags(trim($_POST['categorydescription']));
         $model->save(false); 

         $category_list=Invoice::getCategoryName();
         $test="";
         $test = ' <option value="">Select Category</option>';  
         foreach($category_list as $value ){
                $test .= "<option >{$value['category_name']}</option>";    
         }
         echo $test;
    }
```

Model function

```
public function getCategoryName() {

    $id = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('category_name')
            ->from('add_new_category c')
            ->queryAll();
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: using yii framework in php

Answer (score 0):

You can add unique rule into your `AddNewCategory` model like below:

```
array('fieldName','unique','className'=>__CLASS__,'attributeName'=>'columnName','allowEmpty'=>FALSE)
```

By now, You have a rule, which denies to insert new record with existing value.

Another alternative way would be using `exist()` like below:

```
$exist=AddNewCategory::model()->exist(array('columnName'=>'VALUE'));
```

Which `$exist` variable holds a Boolean value which means whether a record exists with entered condition or not.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#exists-detail